# Qt Widgets & Android: Can't find some widgets/style not fitting

Tags: android, c++, qt, widget

Today I've been using Qt to create really simple Android apps and mostly it works fine.

I'm using Qt Widgets because I'm used to it and most of the stuff transfers fine to the Android style.
In [this article](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/12/03/native-android-style-in-qt-5-4/) I noticed some widgets that I can't find in Qt Designer. I'm wondering how to get the options menu on the top right (three dots) and the tab widget (?) on the very bottom.

The tab widget in Qt Designer works in Android, but the style does not fit. Do I have to use Qt Quick for example the options and the Android tab bar?

[image: Picture of my application.]

Answer (score 0):

Qt GUI not a native one .Qt just emulate the GUI to be like android when you deploy it to android ,but sure can't in all times.